# Count lines of C source code using python with preprocessed file as input

Tags: python, c

I have to count how many lines of code in a C file using Python. But the problem is, the input is a preprocessed file (with extension `.i`). So all the macros are extended and all the comments are deleted. How can I (using python) count the original C source code with the preprocessed file as an input?

Comment: If you don't have the original source file, there's no way to know its contents. Preprocessing is a one-way transformation of the code.

Comment: With that said, there *is* a way to remove some of the code that was added by header files, by parsing and detecting the `#line` (or similar) directive in the preprocessed source. These can contain file-names, which lets you detect which parts *might* have come from a header file. This is definitely not trivial to handle though, and not something that can be counted on to be correct. I really recommend you try to get a hold of the original source file instead.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I have the original files in another directory that's not used as the input. The input must be the preprocessed file. Is there anyway to do it?

Comment: Why do you need to use the preprocessed file? What is the actual and real problem that's supposed to solve? Please [edit] your question to ask about that actual problem directly instead. Also include all your assignment requirements and limitations, and if possible the actual assignment itself copy-pasted as text, in full and complete.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude that's the actual problem i'm having. I have a program processing metrics of preprocessed file unrelated with this problem. In that program, I also need to show the amount of lines in the C file. The input must be preprocessed file, that's the only limitation relevant for this problem.

Comment: You can't create information out of nothing. You have file that does not contain comments. How do you expect the program to count those comments if they aren't there?

Comment: @matszwecja That's exactly why i'm asking the question :) Is there anyway to access the C file from the preprocessed file..... But i guess there is no way

Comment: It seems that you have access to both the original and the preprocessed file. From the name of the preprocessed file it might be possible to guess the name of the original source file, so if you know the path to its directory you can get it to count the number of lines in the original source file. Also, if the first `#line` directive in the preprocessed file have a filename ending in `.c` then it's likely the name of the original source file as well, and you can use that to find the original source file to count its lines.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: You can't.

The information needed was lost in the processing step. You will have to revise your goal of being able to count the lines in the original file and likely try to find an equivalent metric that applies the .i file.

I would think about how you would have used the line count, if you could do it, and what remaining information gets you as close in the next step.